# Make base NVI virtual function private?

Tags: c++, inheritance, c++17, non-virtual-interface

Imagine I have some NVI interface that allows for customization points via virtual functions.
And those virtual functions are designated **solely** for customization within the NVI and should never be invocable outside its context (explicitly called by derived classes elsewhere).

Making those functions `private` disallows the inheriting classes to call it explicitly (which is intended). But it also prevents the class from calling a *default* implementation (which is not intended).

I know I can write a comment to say "never call the base function outside the overriden function", but it leaves the ways to violate the interface.

Here's a small example:

```
class nvi
{
public:
    void operator()(int i) const {
        // do stuff
        _customization(i);
        // other stuff
    }

protected:
    ~nvi() = default;

private:
    virtual void _customization(int) const {}
};

class custom final : public nvi
{
public:
    void some_unrelated_func() {
        // this should not be possible
        // base::_customization(815);
    }

private:
    void _customization(int i) const override {
        // do custom stuff

        // this should be possible
        nvi::_customization(i);
    }
};
```

**Is it possible to make the virtual function private in the base class and still be able to call in derived, but only in the overriden?**

---

This is an *XY* question, but the *X* is not under my control here. Personally I think that having the function `protected` is ok when it doesn't mutate the state or have any observable side effects, so I wouldn't care if inherited classes would call explicitly call it somewhere else...
Also, the possible solution should not be more complicated than the simple comment about the proper usage.

Comment: You'd have to make the base class's `_customization` function **`protected:`** to be able to call it from a derived class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can modify `nvi` this is possible. Here's the full code, with an explanation to follow:

```
#include <cstdio>

class nvi
{
public:
    void operator()(int i) const {
        // do stuff
        _customization(i, private_tag{});
        // other stuff
    }

protected:
    class private_tag {
        explicit private_tag() = default;
        friend class nvi;
    };

    ~nvi() = default;
    virtual void _customization(int, private_tag) const {
        std::printf("Hello");
    }
};

class custom final : public nvi
{
public:
    void some_unrelated_func() {
        // Not possible, can't get private_tag from anywhere
        // nvi::_customization(815, private_tag{});
    }

private:
    void _customization(int i, private_tag key) const override {
        // do custom stuff

        // this is possible
        nvi::_customization(i, key);
        std::printf(" world!\n");
    }
};
```

The idea is basically to just use tag-dispatch. We define a type `private_tag`, which can be named or copied by any sub-class, but can only be constructed inside the scope of `nvi` and nowhere else. This idiom encodes "access rights" in values that we can pass around.

So `operator(int)` creates a `private_tag` and passes it to `_customization`. Then it follow that any `_customization` override can either ignore the tag or it can pass it to some function that accepts it (such as `nvi::_customization` or `_customization` in any class between the final overrider and `nvi`).

Other member functions can't call `nvi::_customization` (or even their *own* `_customization`<sup>1</sup>) because they have no way to create a `private_tag`. This gives us the semantics you want more or less.

---

<sub><sup>1</sup> - Not really that limiting because we can always have `_customization` delegate to some private function that we *may* call.</sub>

Comment: This is nice. I was considering passing a wrapped default-callable as an argument. But would it work with several layers? In case you don't have `final`. This is the way company's architecture is made - "classic OOP", and I don't have control over this

Comment: @SergeyKolesnik - Do you mean several layers of inheritance? Yes it should work. The NVI passes the key to the final overrider. Then in the body of that function we can call any `_customization` along the chain (so long as it's protected and not private), since we too have a key to pass.